# How do I find out why email may be rejected on my Exchange 2013?

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012, logging, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

I'm currently running Server 2012 with I believe Exchange 2013.

I have a log server that needs to send email notifications to my email. This is an internal log server so I was going to point it to our internal Exchange server to send those emails out. For authentication i'm using my personal work email so I know the email and password is correct and that no SMTP relay should be needed.

The test email doesn't go through, however.

What is the best way to track down why the email may be getting rejected? I used the **Get-MessageTrackingLog** Cmdlet but it doesn't seem to be giving me any good information.

I'm assuming I may have a port wrong or something, but I want to see if I can track down a log or something that's telling me why that email may be rejected.

I'm using port 587 and set encryption to Allowed, but i'm not sure if that's correct. I know we use SSL/TLS but I believe the logs should tell me if it's the wrong port or if it's being rejected for another reason.

Any help at all that could point me in the right direction of troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated! Thankyou.

Comment: - How are you trying to send E-Mails from the log server? - What system is it running on? - Do you have any way to see the reply of your Exchange Server (if it's actually hitting it)?

Comment: The log server basically has a spot to type in your SMTP server info. The options are the typical setup like IP address of server, port, encryption, and authentication info. I used my email address for authentication as I know its a valid account and then said encryption is fine etc. There is a test email button, but the email never made it through. There is no rejection response or anything like that which is why I'm trying to look on the Exchange side.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on logging on the Receive Connectors. That will show you if the traffic is actually hitting the server.

Are you sending email to external recipients or just internal? If internal you don't need to authenticate. If external then you do - I would suggest a dedicated receive connector and then restrict it to the IP address of the server with that app. Then when you enable logging you will not get drowned by the traffic.

Comment: Thanks, I will add a connector for the internal log server to see if the relay helps and I'll also look into turning on logging.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the receive connector has this server configured to relay, by IP address or range. Then use that log server to telnet to the server's port 587 or port 25. I would start with port 25 and test internal relay before moving on to configure things like authentication and external recipients. Syntax for your telnet test can be found here [XFOR: Telnet to Port 25 to Test SMTP Communication](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/153119)